# Alternative to welding steel

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, welding

I am going to buy two steel hemispheres, 400 mm in diameter and 0.8 mm thick, to join them and create a sphere. Of these:

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Large-Metal-Half-Sphere-dome-Plain_1600340495245.html?spm=a2700.12243863.0.0.21dd3e5f9X0RMl

My problem is that I can't solder it because I have to constantly open and close it. I can't put screws because inside it must be smooth.

Outside should also be smooth, that's my second problem. I thought of something that would hug him very strongly from the outside.

Perhaps a ducktape like this:
https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/product/B07B3LCQY5/

I think it's possible, I don't know, confirm me, please. But, the problem is that if I close it with ducktape I won't be able to open it. Do you give me any good solution? Please.

Comment: Cut the ducktape then you can open it. And if you weld it how do you expect to open it?

Comment: I'm looking for a more elegant way to do it. For example, there are clamps for plastic pipes, I would like something like that. Make mounting and dismounting simple and safe. In relation to that last question, do you mean to do it as hinges?

Comment: Your clamping idea is a good one. Not knowing what the application for the sphere, but a purpose built clamping cradle might be what you need.

Comment: You need to define the level of "smoothness" you require on the inside and outside, because obviously duct tape or any clamp are going to raise the surface somewhat. If you can tollerate a 10mm protrusion on the outside you could just add a flange or some tabs with screw holes.

Comment: Put a grove on the join and use a o ring to keep it closed? Add threads?

Comment: Since for some reason nobody asked yet: What are you planning to do with this thing?